# Field Proofs with Multiplicative Inverses

Tags: field-theory, inverse

I've been staring at these two for a while and I can't come up with anything concrete to start. Hints on how to begin would be greatly appreciated, full solutions are not necessary (and preferably avoided).

Suppose that $F$ is a field and prove the following:

For all $0\ne a \in F, -a\ne 0$ and $(-a)^{-1}=-(a^{-1})$.

For all nonzero $a,b\in F$ and $ab\ne 0$ and $a^{-1}+b^{-1}=(a+b)(ab)^{-1}$

These appeared similar enough to not warrant two posts. Though, I don't know where to begin so I could very well be wrong. I've been staring at the list of axioms for Fields and can't determine how any of them are useful to begin.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing you want to show is that multiplicative inverses are unique: that is, choose $x \neq 0$ in your field. Then the field axioms guarantee *an*  element $y$ such that $xy = 1$, but you can conclude more strongly that there is a *unique* such $y$.

Given that, it isn't so bad. Remember that the inverse of $x$ is defined to be the (now unique) element such that $xy = 1$. So in the first case, you want to show that $(-a)^{-1} = -(a^{-1})$. Well, all you have to do is show that
$$
(-a) \cdot \big(-(a^{-1})\big) = 1
$$
from the above considerations. Now play with associativity and commutativity a little bit, and you should get what you want.

For the second question, it's even easier. Consider multiplying both sides of the (supposed!) equality by $(ab)$.

To be precise, compute first the left-hand side:
$$
\begin{align}
(a^{-1} + b^{-1})(ab) &= a^{-1}(ab) + b^{-1}(ab) \\
&= (a^{-1}a)b + b^{-1}(ba) \\
&= b + (b^{-1}b)a \\
&= b + a \\
&= a + b
\end{align}
$$
where on each line we only use one axiom at a time. Now, do the same for the left-hand side, and verify that the two sides are equal.